# Can you tell Vim to open a different file than the one passed on the commandline or to :e?

Tags: vim

I want to teach Vim how to open Perl 5 modules from names like `File::Find`.  I already have a wrapper script written in Perl 5 that handles the commandline (see below), but I would like to be able to say things like `:tabe File::Find` and have it really execute `:tabe /home/cowens/apps/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.0/lib/5.14.0/File/Find.pm`.

My current plan is to somehow use `autocmd BufNewFile` and/or `autocmd BufPreRead`, but I can't figure out how to switch the file name.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = @ARGV;
for my $file (@files) {
    next if -f $file; #skip files that really exist

    #convert from module name to module file
    (my $module = $file) =~ s{::}{/}g;
    $module .= ".pm";

    #look for module in the include paths
    for my $dir (@INC) {
        my $candidate = "$dir/$module";
        if (-f $candidate) {
            $file = $candidate;
            last;
        }
    }
}

#replace this script with vim
exec "vim", "-p", @files;
```

Comment: Have you looked at and dismissed `ctags`?

Comment: @searlea No, I have never used `ctags`, I assume I can say `:help ctags` in Vim to learn more?

Comment: Yes... vim's got help on it.  It's help with jumping directly from function references to source definitions etc, going well beyond simply starting or opening a file based on a module name.

Comment: @searlea It looks like `ctags` is a way to execute a command based on text in the current buffer.  It also looks like it requires an index that must be modified everytime you add a file (to map the string to the command).  This isn't really what I am looking for.  I want to be able to edit any file, not just files included in the current file.  One problem with `ctags` is that the file I get when I say `:tabe Foo` could change depending on my environment.  This could probably be fixed by a complex enough command, but then why wouldn't I just use that command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing

```
:verbose au BufReadCmd
```

Will tell you how other types of plugins do this (e.g. zip, netrw, fugitive). Sample output that should give you plenty of ideas:

```
zip  BufReadCmd
    zipfile:* call zip#Read(expand("<amatch>"), 1)
    Last set from C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\plugin\zipPlugin.vim
    *.zip     call zip#Browse(expand("<amatch>"))
    Last set from C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\plugin\zipPlugin.vim

Network  BufReadCmd
    ftp://*   exe "silent doau BufReadPre ".fnameescape(expand("<amatch>"))|call netrw#Nread(2,expand("<amatch>"))|exe "silent doau BufReadPost ".fnameescape(expand("<amatch>"))
    Last set from C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\plugin\netrwPlugin.vim
    http://*  exe "silent doau BufReadPre ".fnameescape(expand("<amatch>"))|call netrw#Nread(2,expand("<amatch>"))|exe "silent doau BufReadPost ".fnameescape(expand("<amatch>"))
    Last set from C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\plugin\netrwPlugin.vim

fugitive_files  BufReadCmd
    *.git/index
              exe s:BufReadIndex()
    Last set from C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\plugin\fugitive.vim
    *.git/*index*.lock
              exe s:BufReadIndex()
    Last set from C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\plugin\fugitive.vim
    fugitive://**//[0-3]/**
              exe s:BufReadIndexFile()
    Last set from C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\plugin\fugitive.vim
    fugitive://**//[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]*
              exe s:BufReadObject()
    Last set from C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\plugin\fugitive.vim
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider using `ctags`. If you're able to run the ctags process over your source code, you should be able to get to a point where you simply do:

```
vim -t File::Find
```

Vim has information about this (`:help vim`)  I think [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) probably goes well beyond what you're trying to do, allowing you to jump from the middle of one source file to the original function definition in another.

Comment: Vim already knows how do most of this for Perl 5.  I can hit `gF` while over a module name and have it open that module.  The problem comes when I am in file A and want to open File B, but File A contains no references to File B.

Comment: Hmm, that does have some merit then, but I would still have to keep an index of files->commands up-to-date. The problem there is that I have more than one sandbox.  So when I am in sandbox A, I want A/A and A/B, but when I am in sandbox B, I want B/A and B/B. I can change which sandbox I am using by changing directory and sourcing an environment file. If I were to switch to using `ctags`, I would need to reindex. That might not be that painful, and it sounds like it would be less work than getting the `autocmd`s to work properly.  I am going to give it a try.

Comment: I don't think you need to reindex, I believe you can use more than one tags file... See `:help 'tags'` and `:help file-searching` to set things up so you automatically pick a different tags file based on which sandbox you're in (e.g. by crawling up the directory tree from your current source file.)

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't look like there is a `:tabtag` or similar command that would open the tag in a new tab.  I hate buffers, is there something I am missing?  I guess I could create my own command that opens a new tab then runs `:tag`.

Comment: That's one thing I haven't found in the help docs; I think you'll have to make your own commands for that.

Comment: Another downside is that I will have to reindex when new files are added, but I guess I can just put hooks into darcs and git to trigger a reindexing when I pull or add a file.

Comment: There is no `:tabtag`, what you do is `:tab stag`.  `:stag` by itself splits the window and jumps to the tag, adding `:tab` in front says "do this window split operation but into a new tab instead."  This works for many (all?) vim commands that do splits.

Comment: The key to using ctags is just to keep your indices local to the thing they're indexing.  You can have multiple tags files listed in your vimrc and you can change the variables (automatically) when changing buffers if you want to search in different orders.  Changing environment variables requires restarting vim to take effect so it's best (IMO) to set things up so that the settings "know" the current sandbox.  (This is exactly what I do so that I use the tags file associated with the project that I'm currently in.)

Answer (score 2):

For opening those files manually I would recommend to use `:find` and
`:tabfind` commands instead of `:edit` and `:tabedit` respectively.  The
difference between these two pairs of commands is that the former ones look
for a file not only in the current path, but also in directories listed in
`path` option (see `:help 'path'`).  If you add your Perl `@INC` directories
to Vim `path` option, you can quickly locate a module file by using `:find` or
`:tabfind` commands.  For example, to open a new tab page and edit
`File::Find` module file in you can type

```
:tabfind File/Find.pm
```

(You don't have to type the whole sub-path manually since `:find` and
`:tabfind` completion takes the current `path` value into account.)

To locating those files automatically by module name using `gf`, `^Wf`,
`^Wgf`, you need to additionally change (either with filetype plugin or
autocommand) the following options for Perl files.

```
:set isfname+=:
:set suffixesadd+=.pm
:set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'::','/','g')
```

After these options (as well as `path` option containing Perl `@INC`
directories) are set, you can easily open module files using `gf`-like
commands on corresponding module names.

Comment: Nope, that is a non-starter.  The trick here isn't just the path, it is also the conversion from `File::Find` to `File/Find.pm`.

Comment: @Chas.: You can easily achieve this behavior using Vim built-in mechanisms.  See the updated answer.

Comment: Again, I want to be able to say `:tabe File::Find` or something like it.  `gf` already finds Perl modules without a problem in Vim 7.  I want to be editing file A then realize I need to be editing file B and be able to open it even though file B is not mentioned anywhere in file A.  I often get module names from other sources (like email, IM, logs, etc.) and I am tired of having to make the changes manually.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy solution based on sehe's answer below.  Current problems:

1. the file it writes is the original name, not the munged name
2. it looks like the autocommands that set the filetype are running too soon, not at all, or are confused.
3. it is using an external command to do the work
4. it is specific to the munging I want (i.e. it is not general)

When I have more downtime, I hope to fix all of the above and turn it into a plugin.

in `.vimrc`

```
autocmd BufReadCmd * r!cat_perl %
```

in `cat_perl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub cat {
    my $file = shift;
    open my $fh, "<", $file
        or die "could not open $file: $!";
    print while <$fh>;
    exit;
}

my $file = shift;

cat $file if -f $file;

#convert from module name to module file
(my $module = $file) =~ s{::}{/}g;
$module .= ".pm";

#look for module in the include paths
for my $dir (@INC) {
    my $candidate = "$dir/$module";
    cat $candidate if -f $candidate;
}
print "";
```

Answer (score 0):

This may actually be possible with vim's `gf` command (go to file).

In your code, if you see a string like File::Find, place your cursor over it and in normal mode type `gf`. For me, that immediately takes me to the File::Find package.

I think this is native as part of the perl filetype libraries because it works for me when executing vim with `--noplugin`.

Comment: It is and it doesn't do what I want.  I want to be able to open any file, not just files that happen to be referenced in the current file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [working example showing how to use the BufReadCmd autocmd](https://gist.github.com/1116249/) to edit a file other than the one specified (in this case editing a corresponding .scss file when you open a .css file).